# Autocompletion from stdin with clang

Tags: c++, c, clang, code-completion

I have set up an environment for autocompletion in Emacs, using clang 2.8 as the parser. It works well, but relies on saving the currently edited buffer to file before completion. This is slow, so I am trying to get clang to parse a file given to it via stdin instead, without luck so far.

The command line I feed clang when parsing a file is as follows:

```
clang -cc1 -fsyntax-only -Iinclude/ -code-completion-at foo.cpp:10:20 foo.cpp
```

This works well. But attempts to read from stdin fail. I've tried this:

```
cat foo.cpp | clang -xc++ -cc1 -fsyntax-only -Iinclude/ -code-completion-at -:10:20 -
```

But that makes clang terminate without making any completions and prints the warnings:

```
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-cc1'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-code-completion-at'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-:10:20'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work if you specify `-cc1` before `-x c++`?

Comment: Hmm, no, but the error is different. It now simply says "fatal error: cannot locate code-completion file -".

Comment: That's unfortunate, if I use `clang -cc1 -x c++ -fsyntax-only -code-completion-at -:7:15 - <test.cc` it works fine. Clang 2.0 FWIW.

Comment: Ah, damn. I just tried a freshly built HEAD revision of the clang trunk, and it works. Typical, that means the built-in version of my OS won't work. Thanks for clearing things up for me.