# How to enable completion of C++ template classes in vim using YouCompleteMe

Tags: c++, templates, vim, clang, code-completion

When using the vim plugin YouCompleteMe for C++ code completion I stumbled over an issue.
Using nested template classes stops the completion to work properly.

Consider the following example to reproduce the behaviour:

```
#include <vector>

template<class T>
class foo {
  public:
  void Init();

  private:
  struct bar {
    int foobar;
  };
  bar one_bar;
  std::vector<foo<T>::bar> some_bars;
};

template<class T>
void foo<T>::Init(){
  one_bar.foobar = 0; // completion as expected
  some_bars.at(0).foobar = 0; // no completion neither for "at" nor for "foobar"
}
```

The code completion for "some_bars" is not working at all while "one_bar" behaves as expected.

How can I get completion working for this code? Is this issue related to the setup and should actually work or is it a bug in YCM?

My system is debian jessie/sid based, vim version 7.4, YCM latest version from GitHub.

Edit:
There are similar issues reported in YCMs bug tracker:
https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/243
https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/530

Seems to be a bug in clang rather than in YCM. Can someone confirm this?

Edit2:
I opened another issue in the YCM issue tracker.
https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/1170

The intention is to get more information on what the bug in clang exactly is and finally to make a bug report in the clang issue tracker.

Edit3:
I followed the proposed procedure from RedX and fed my code in clang to get completions.
Clang does not provide any suggestions for the discussed positions in the code.
This clearly is the reason why YCM fails to make suggestions in vim and it has nothing to do with YCM or vim.

A bug report in the clang issue tracker has been filed:
http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=20973

Comment: The chances of this question ever getting a convincing answer on SO are close to 0. YCM is only a hacky frontend for clang so why don't you try [clang's issue tracker](http://llvm.org/bugs/describecomponents.cgi?product=clang) directly?

Comment: Valloric already seems to have confirmed it is a bug/not supported in clang in the issues you posted.

Comment: @FDinoff : the bounty is for explaining where exactly the issue is and how it can be fixed.

Comment: @romainl : I don't know anything about clang so I wouldn't know where to start. Hence the bounty: I need someone to explain where the issue in clang is and possibly open an issue there. YCM is an awesome tool for many people, this is a chance to make it better.

Comment: … and the wrong place to do that, with or without a bounty. The clang mailing list or their issue tracker is where to start. *No answer in three weeks,* seriously. Had this question been asked on the proper channel to begin with it would probably have already been solved by now.

Comment: @romainl it's not my question. And I told you, I don't know what the issue with clang is, not how it is used, hence I can't post on their mailing list.

Comment: @static_rtti, the best way to know what the issue is is to ask the people responsible for clang and they are not here, they are on the mailing list and on the issue tracker. Valloric won't submit it to clang, you won't submit it to clang, the OP won't submit it to clang either, nobody will give you an answer here and the issue will remain unsolved. Go, team!

Comment: @romainl : Valloric said there is an issue with clang, but he failed to mention what it is. How can I report something to clang if I don't know what it is? "There is a problem with clang" or "YCM doesn't work" will probably not be very well received on the clang mailing list.

Comment: Try feeding this snippet to clang and asking it to provide you with the completions. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646643/autocompletion-from-stdin-with-clang) on how to do it from the command-line/std in. Then maybe you can create a replicable example.

Comment: @Phil : maybe you should try posting on the clang mailing list as well? Your bug is likely to sit for a few months before being closed as invalid if you don't make sure with the community that you followed the right process.

Comment: This is a clang bug. I tried this snippet in Xcode and also get no completion. Xcode completion is clang-based like YCM.

Comment: @Stackia: a bug has been reported to clang: http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=20973 . Unfortunately it hasn't even been acknowledged yet.

Comment: Mmm, no activity on the clang bug report. Perhaps this is not the correct way to get attention?

Answer (score 3):

I think, under the rules of C++, you cannot get completion in this case.

Without knowledge of the type `T`, we don't know what methods `std::vector<T>` will have, as each instansiation of a template in C++ can have different methods.

Comment: In the code shown here, all completions are clearly known, even without knowing the type T. It is not a std::vector<T> but a std::vector<foo<T>::bar>.

Answer (score 0):

As @Chris Jefferson mentioned above it is theoretically impossible .
This comment doesn't take in account template specializations

> In the code shown here, all completions are clearly known, even without knowing the type T. It is not a std::vector but a std::vector<foo::bar>

This occurred to me in a very different context while I was trying to write a specialization for a template without deducting a template.I will provide my example to make the situation clear.  So lets say you have an enumerator and you have a meta_info class that defines a size for an enumerator it takes by template so :

```cpp
enum class e{a,b};
template <class Enum>
struct meta_info;
template<>
meta_info<e>{
    static constexpr size_t s=2;
}
```

Ok this works and it is nice to have but what happens if you try to do the same thing in an enumerator nested in a template class?

```cpp
template <class Tag>
struct str{
   enum class e{a,b};
}
template <class Enum>
struct meta_info;
template<T>
meta_info<str<T>::e>{
    static constexpr size_t s=2;
}
```

This doesn't compile as someone else(another part of the code) might change `e` with another specialization.There is no formal way for a compiler to know if a specialization changes a type even at the first passes of compilation. Having in mind that auto-complete tools most of the times just use the includes paths to find a suggestion this would be impossible. So in the future I would like to see in ycm something like an informal instantiation  [like VS has done](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/template-intellisense-improvements-for-visual-studio-2019-preview-2/)